# "Failed to download repository information" error

Tags: apt, update-manager

I have recently installed ubuntu 11.10. But when i try to install a software it tries to 'updating cache' but after a while, it stops, showing:

```
                         Failed to download repository information
                          Check your internet connection
```

so, now i am totally unable to install any software in my ubuntu.

Please,let me know how to solve the problem.

Comment: what faults do you get when you run `sudo apt-get update` on a terminal? faults?

Comment: change the server to main server, from the software resources menu option in the ubuntu software center

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the server to main server, from the software resources menu option in the Ubuntu Software Center.